# checking out "tips on the gun"

Tags: word-meaning

Reading this [**article,**](https://www.yahoo.com/news/ohio-woman-falsely-called-police-154003651.html) I encountered a line which I don't understand.

> Capt. Jake Smallfield, a spokesman for the Ravenna Police Department, said he reviewed all the videos from the incident and thought everyone was professional during the incident. He said police **have to check out tips on guns.**

[**This dictionary**](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/tip) has many entries and the dictionary I subscribe is no use.

What does Capt. Jake Samllfield say police have to check out?

Does the tips mean a number(no definition in the dictionary)of guns or the untidy parts?

Comment: From your source, the closest one is #9, but a closer definition is the one I give in the duplicate: He said police have to check out tips [= information provided to the police or authorities/them] on guns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

“tips on guns” is using this definition from that dictionary:

> 9. COUNTABLE NOUN
>
> A tip is a useful piece of advice.

This is the sense that is used in “tip off”:

> tip off
>
> PHRASAL VERB
>
> If someone tips you off, they give you information about something that has happened or is going to happen.
>
> Greg tipped police off on his car phone about a suspect drunk driver. [VERB noun PARTICLE]
>
> He was arrested two days later after a friend tipped off the FBI. [VERB PARTICLE noun]

So, the author is saying that when the police receive a *tip*, or are *tipped off*, about guns, they are required to investigate.

Comment: Would you kindly enlighten or confirm with me that the Capt. Jake Smallfield is Police have to check the calls or information that leads to the guns(holders) as their job?

Comment: I'm not sure quite what you're asking, @Kentaro, but I think the answer is No. When they receive a tip about guns (it doesn't make it clear what, but probably that guns are being used or handled in a way that might be illegal. It's not that they have to check the calls: they have to respond to the calls by investigating whether what the calls are talking about is a police matter.

Comment: @ColinFine Thank you for the feedback. Anyhow, if I understand the Stephen's correctly, I would be able to conclude that the Capt. Jake Smallfield is saying Police job is checking tips (info, call, or "tips",  you name it) on guns as if it is a routine.

Comment: @Kentaro In the US, it is usually up to the police to decide what alleged crimes they will investigate. For instance, after many mass shootings, it was discovered that the shooter had often been previously reported to the police, but those reports were ignored. Smallfield is saying that, in contrast, his police dept investigates *all* tips about gun crimes, implying this is a routine task his officers are well trained on and experienced with.

Comment: @StephenS Got it with much appreciation(m_m). Thank you^^.